# Cannot install npm package (fsevents) on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, npm, macos-catalina

When I run `npm install express --save` this command, I'm getting an error. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Error:

```
> fsevents@1.2.11 install /Users/delowar/Desktop/ytdl/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.7.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/delowar/Desktop/ytdl/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v13.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok

> fsevents@1.2.11 install /Users/delowar/Desktop/ytdl/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.7.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/delowar/Desktop/ytdl/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v13.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/HEAD/macOS_Catalina.md

Comment: Problem solved, I've shared my solution. Thanks

Comment: Just remove node_modules and reinstall the packages, boom will fix the issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Problem solved by reinstalling xcode command line tools.

Open Terminal & paste these code:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

then

```
xcode-select --install
```

> Note: - Be Careful using `rm` command

Comment: FWIW  --  I didn't have to use `-f` option but I did have to use elevated permissions, `sudo`.  But the process worked great!

Comment: I also had to remove `node_modules` and reinstall npm packages for my project, as recommended by https://stackoverflow.com/a/67919891/3046255, to fully solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to use the rm -rf command so an alternative option when you have brew installed with the "trash" formulae you can do on your terminal is :

```
trash Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

And then

```
xcode-select --install
```

If you don't have trash installed then you can do it on your terminal :
https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/trash

```
brew install trash
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the instructions above didn't work. So, I came across a different solution:

```
> xcode-select -print-path
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

```
> sudo xcode-select --reset
```

```
> xcode-select -print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not related to Xcode Command Line Tools.

**Preferred**: Just delete the `node_modules` folder and execute `npm install` again, the problem will be gone. It is due to the system protection of macOS since Catalina, which detects the executables are downloaded from the Internet instead of generated by the `npm` commands.

Alternatively, you can clear the extended attributes, which marks the files are downloaded from the Internet (even though it's zipped and unzipped afterwards), in the `node_modules` folder:

```
xattr -rc node_modules/
```