# macOs Catalina - “fse.node” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified. While doing npm run dev or watch

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

On macOS Catalina 10.15.3, I am getting the below error message while running `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`. It seems like something to do with `nodejs` but no idea know how to resolve it.

> “fse.node” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
>   macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware.

[image]

Comment: Did it's developer not have it notarized?

Comment: Actually I keep switching computers and It is my own another mac. I have copied the project from that mac to MacBook.

Comment: Sounds like a no.  Did notarization solve the problem?

Comment: @RichardBarber I am not sure what that is and how to do it. Can you please guide me?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Go to System preferences > Security & privacy > General and you should see a "Allow anyway" button below. Click. That's it. (When that info box appear on screen)

You may need repeat this action couple of times.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Mac OS Big Sur 11.1 :(

Answer (score 32):

The accepted answer worked for me, but I had to click on "cancel" for the option "Allow anyway" to appear in system preferences.

So if you don't see the "Allow Anyway" button, try clicking "cancel" on the popup.

[image: Screenshot of the system preferences pane Security & Privacy]

Answer (score 23):

If you received a project, and didn't run `npm install` yourself, you might ended up with a `/node_modules` folder (it might be a hidden folder by default) with modules that doesn't have the good authorisations on your computer.

The good way, IMO:

- remove `node_modules`;
- `npm install`;
- `npm run dev` (or similar) should work now.

Comment: In addition to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59905994/3046255, doing a clean npm install, as you recommend, solved the issue. Thanks!